# MySQL Workbench editor highlighted text color

Tags: colors, mysql-workbench

I have been unable to figure out how to change the text color in MySQL Workbench when the **text is highlighted**. I'm happy with all my other text and background colors in the `code_editor.xml` file (which I have just spent 2 hours customizing to resemble SQL Server Management Studio colors):

```
<style id= "0" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DEFAULT                  -->
<style id= "1" fore-color="#008000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id= "2" fore-color="#008000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id= "3" fore-color="#A58E37" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id= "4" fore-color="#A58E37" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id= "5" fore-color="#A58E37" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id= "6" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id= "7" fore-color="#0000FF" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id= "8" fore-color="#0000FF" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id= "9" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="10" fore-color="#C04000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="11" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="12" fore-color="#FF0000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="13" fore-color="#FF0000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="14" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="15" fore-color="#C040C0" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="16" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="17" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="18" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="19" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="20" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="21" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="22" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->

<!-- These two are for scintilla globally. -->
<style id="32" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#E3DDBF" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_DEFAULT                      THIS IS THE ONE FOR THE BACKGROUND!!!!! -->
<style id="33" fore-color="#000000" back-color="#DDDDDD" bold="No" />   <!-- STYLE_LINENUMBER                   -->

<!-- All styles again in their variant in a hidden command (with a 0x40 offset). -->
<style id="65" fore-color="#999999" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT                  -->
<style id="66" fore-color="#999999" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE              -->
<style id="67" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_VARIABLE                 -->
<style id="68" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SYSTEMVARIABLE           -->
<style id="69" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KNOWNSYSTEMVARIABLE      -->
<style id="70" fore-color="#FF8080" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_NUMBER                   -->
<style id="71" fore-color="#7AAAD7" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_MAJORKEYWORD             -->
<style id="72" fore-color="#7AAAD7" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_KEYWORD                  -->
<style id="73" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DATABASEOBJECT           -->
<style id="74" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PROCEDUREKEYWORD         -->
<style id="75" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_STRING                   -->
<style id="76" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_SQSTRING                 -->
<style id="77" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_DQSTRING                 -->
<style id="78" fore-color="#FFBB80" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_OPERATOR                 -->
<style id="79" fore-color="#9B859D" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_FUNCTION                 -->
<style id="80" fore-color="#DDDDDD" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_IDENTIFIER               -->
<style id="81" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_QUOTEDIDENTIFIER         -->
<style id="82" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER1                    -->
<style id="83" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER2                    -->
<style id="84" fore-color="#B9CB89" back-color="#707070" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_USER3                    -->
<style id="85" fore-color="#FFBB80" back-color="#909090" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_HIDDENCOMMAND            -->
<style id="86" fore-color="#AAAAAA" back-color="#909090" bold="No" />   <!-- SCE_MYSQL_PLACEHOLDER              -->
```

It's so incredibly tedious in workbench to experiment by changing 1 color code, save, close Workbench, re-open workbench, open a connection, view a sql/text file, evaluate colors...after each change. So I'm hoping somebody will know which style element/attribute needs to change to affect the text color when that text is highlighted. *Note: The highlighted text background color is fine.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So it sounds like you want the color of the **text** (or any typed SQL statements) to change when that text is highlighted (not the highlight color iteself) and from what I can tell, it seems that perhaps the XML file does not have any elements you can change the HTML color code to change that property. If you happen to determine something otherwise that does so this, please tag me back as I'll be curious to hear of this solution. The closest colors I can find are in these fields though but I did not change as you may already know it's none of those: https://i.imgur.com/A2VjRXW.png

Comment: I think that's actually the highlighted color itself but may be worth digging into more in case that helps any but I'm not sure but I wanted to share that with your at a minimum at least just in case.

Comment: I would actually be happy changing *either* the highlight background color or the highlighted text color. The combination I currently have is so low-contrast that I can hardly read it.